# PHP: Where is this variance in json encoding coming from?

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays, that before I `json_encode`, look EXACTLY the same to me in terms of formatting, but once I `json_encode` to send back to my ajax call, there is a variance in the two and I can't figure out where this is coming from.

## Array 1:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Blue
            [1] => A
            [2] => Bob
            [3] => active
            [4] => Yes
            [5] => 0.0079
            [6] => 0.0100
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => Red
            [1] => A
            [2] => Dan
            [3] => unconfirmed
            [4] => Unknown
            [5] => 
            [6] => 
        )


    [54] => Array
        (
            [0] => Green
            [1] => C
            [2] => Matt
            [3] => active
            [4] => Yes
            [5] => 
            [6] =>  
        )

)
```

and after `json_encode($string);`:

```
[["Blue","A","Bob","active","Yes","0.0079","0.0100"],["Red","A","Dan","active","Yes",null,null],["Green","C","Matt","unconfirmed","Yes",null,null]]]
```

**Valid JSON**

## Array 2:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => White
            [1] => A
            [2] => Ann
            [3] => active
            [4] => Yes
            [5] => 0.0079
            [6] => 0.0100
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [0] => Black
            [1] => C
            [2] => Mary
            [3] => active
            [4] => Yes
            [5] => 0.0104
            [6] => 0.0262
        )

    [35] => Array
        (
            [0] => Yellow
            [1] => C
            [2] => Alice
            [3] => active
            [4] => Yes
            [5] => 0.0330
            [6] => 0.0520
        )
)
```

and after `json_encode($secondString);`

```
{"0":["White","A","Ann","active","Yes","0.0079","0.0100"],"12":["Black","C","Mary","active","Yes","0.0104","0.0262"],"35":["Yellow","C","Alice","active","Yes","0.0330","0.0520"]]}
```

**Invalid JSON**

the second array is generated by this line of code:

```
$secondString = array_filter($string, function($value) { return $value[5] !== null; });
```

where in I create a new array by outputting anything from the first array where its 5th value is not blank.  The thing is - sometimes the second array looks exactly the same as the first, after performing this filter, while other times it causes this bad array.

## Question

Why is this second string different from the first, and what are some things that could be causing this? I can't see any physical difference in the format of the two arrays, so I'm not sure what's causing this, and it's obviously not json (I assume) since my ajax call doesn't return it in its success function.

Comment: `json_encode()` doesn't generate invalid JSON.  You have an extra bracket in your output... no idea where that's coming from but I'd bet $5 it's not from `json_encode()`.

Comment: I updated my original post - though I still don't see how this bit of code is causing this.

Comment: My bet is, your example is wrong. Your first json encoding shows that your array keys are contiguous, starting from 0, while your second array has non-contiguous keys.

Comment: @kuroineko - you're absoltuely correct, I took data out of the first string (since it was 54 elements long....), but it WAS contiguous.  I guess I need to make the new array contiguous before I run it through `json_encode`

Comment: ... which you can do easily by running it through `array_values()`, as the poster mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first string is the value returned by `json_encode(array_values($array))`, the second one is returned by `json_encode($array)`.

`array_values()` returns an array that have numeric sequential keys starting with `0`. `json_encode()` produces a representation of a Javascript array from it.

The keys of your array are not sequential. They are `0`, `4` and `54`. `json_encode()` cannot produce a Javascript array from them. It produces a Javascript object in order to preserve the keys.

For the first array there is no need to store the keys in the `JSON` representation. Being numeric sequential starting with `0` they are, in fact, the default keys an array will have in both `PHP` and `Javascript` when elements are added to the array without specifying the keys where they should be stored.

An example:

```
// Encode an array having sequential keys starting from 0
$array = array('zero', 1, 'two');
echo(json_encode($array)."\n");
// produces: ["zero",1,"two"] - Javascript array

// Break the sequence
unset($array[1]);
// the keys are now: 0, 2
echo(json_encode($array)."\n");
// produces: {"0":"zero","2":"two"} - Javascript object

// fix the keys sequence
$array = array_values($array);
// the keys are now: 0, 1
echo(json_encode($array)."\n");
// produces: ["zero","two"] - JS array again

// setting a value at any key different than "2" (the next number in the sequence) will break it again
$array['foo'] = 'bar';
echo(json_encode($array)."\n");
// produces: {"0":"zero","1":"two","foo":"bar"} - object
```

Comment: This is a beautiful answer, and explains exactly what I did wrong.   It also makes sense now why it works SOMETIMES and not others.  In those cases where it just happened to work, maybe those keys that had data in them just happened to be the 1st, 2nd, and 3rd keys of the array, so it was still in sequential order.  I need to go figure out how to re-encode an array whose keys are out of whack.  Thank you!

Comment: I added a fragment of code that displays the behaviour using a smaller array.

Comment: oh - I misunderstood your sentence on what `array_values` does.  It's hard with English as a second language sometimes :).  Thank you!